# Lookup value in arrays based on index

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of the function is to get the index of a string in an input array (arVal), then based on that index, return a string in an output array (arDisplay).

In the code below, I am trying to get "a" as the result but it keeps giving me "b". In the example, I found out that variable pos is 1 instead of 0.

```
Function lookup_Display(val As String, ByRef arVal As Variant, ByRef arDisplay As Variant) As String
    
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = Application.Match(val, arVal, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(pos) Then
        lookup_Display = arDisplay(pos)
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function

Sub test_lookup()
    Debug.Print lookup_Display("1", Array("1", "2"), Array("a", "b"))
End Sub
```

Following @BigBen comment, removing application.match. This one works for me

```
Function lookup_Display(val As String, ByRef arVal As Variant, ByRef arDisplay As Variant) As String
    Dim pos As Long
    For pos = LBound(arVal) To UBound(arVal)
        If arVal(pos) = val Then
            If Not IsError(pos) Then
                lookup_Display = arDisplay(pos)
            End If
        End If
    Next pos

End Function
```

Comment: `Match` is one-based. Plus you need `Dim pos As Variant` or `Dim pos`, because `Application.Match` will return an error if no match. `Else` and `Exit Function` are superfluous.

Comment: @BigBen thanks! I didn't know that ```Application.Match``` is one-based. I updated the function. This works for me.

Comment: FYI in your second block `pos` will never be an error, so you do not need the error check.  Also you can `Exit Function` immediately after `lookup_Display = arDisplay(pos)` unless you expect multiple matches and you only want the *last* one.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the input!